# How does the data get updated in $HTTP.put

Tags: angularjs, http

Currently I am working on an angularJS app. it reads an property file from a repository and output an xeditable table, so you can change all the properties.

The only question I have now is, how do I make http.put request to update data.

assume the properties file have:

```
var data = {'prop1' : 'this', 'prop2' : 'that'};
```

I currently have:

```
$scope.update = function(key,value){
        $http.post('http://blabla.com/properties.json', $scope.data)
        .success(function (data, status) {
        //success code
    })
```

So Assume I updated the **prop1** from **this** to **newProperty**.
Is my code correct? does the file in remote repository get updated?

or do i have to do something like this

```
$scope.update = function(key,value){
            $http.post('http://blabla.com/properties.json', 
             data: { 
                    prop1: 'newProperty' 
             })
            .success(function (data, status) {
            //success code
        })
```

I only changed prop1, do I need to include prop2 also inside the data bracket? What happen when i got like 30 properties, then how do I update only 1 of the values using Http.put?

thanks

Comment: you should do console.log($scope.yourvar); and look the result in the console.

Answer (score 0):

That URL won't work. You need a server-side API that can handle file uploads. That's not possible with Angular alone.

e.g.

```
$http.put('http://blabla.com/properties_api', $scope.data);
```

Also you've written `$http.post` up there, and that will (and should) fail unless the data doesn't exist in your repository. Change it to `put` if you're updating, 'post' only if you're creating.

---

Generally, uploading the full object is the way to go, otherwise the server is likely to treat the lack of other data as an explicit intention to delete that data. If you've got 30 properties, upload all 30.
That depends on how your server code handles this upload. If you write it yourself it'll do whatever you want with the data you give it.

That being said, if you've got a lot of data it can be unfeasible to upload it all, so you can create multiple APIs that can each handle a particular type of data.

e.g.

```
$http.put('http://blabla.com/properties_api/prop1_handler', $scope.data);
```